Post-hoc for GLMM with polynomials/splines
I'm trying to do a post-hoc on my GLMM but I'm not sure I'm doing it right.
I test the effect of continuous variables X and Y on a binary response Z with my IDs as a random effect with this code:
model <- glmer(Z ~ ns(X, 3) * ns(Y, 2) + (1 | id),
           data = df,
           family = binomial(link = "logit"),
           control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", 
                       optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05)),
           nAGQ = 1)

After doing the ‘classic’ analyses, I'd like to know if there's a difference when Y = 0. Here's what I did:
emm <- emtrends(model, ~ X * Y, var = "X",
            max.degree = 3,
            at = list(Y = c(0)))
test(emm, adjust = "bonferroni")

That give me:
 degree = linear:
         Y        X        X.trend      SE  df z.ratio p.value
        0    -5.79       -0.18800 0.06186 Inf  -3.039  0.0024

degree = quadratic:
         Y        X        X.trend      SE  df z.ratio p.value
        0    -5.79        0.01569 0.00518 Inf   3.030  0.0024

degree = cubic:
         Y        X        X.trend      SE  df z.ratio p.value
        0    -5.79        0.00295 0.00143 Inf   2.067  0.0388

I deduce from this that there does seem to be a difference in the Y = 0 condition. To go further, I've selected some X values that I want to compare two by two in this condition:
emm <- emtrends(model, pairwise ~ X * Y, var = "X",
                max.degree = 3,
                at = list(X = c(-16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 
                          0, 2),
                          Y = c(0)))

test(emm, adjust = "bonferroni")

Is it any good?
UPDATE
Comparing trends didn't seem relevant in my case because I want to compare the probabilities at specific point of X according to Y = 0. So it seems more relevant to use emmeans:
emm <- emmeans(model, pairwise ~ X,
           at = list(X = c(-16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2),
                     Y = c(-0)),
           type = "response")
test(emm, adjust = "bonferroni")

Which gives me 45 comparisons.

In the first analysis, you should clarify that these estimates are all conditioned on X being equal to its mean (it does show the X in the output, but still). Also, these are not differences, but rather estimates of the linear, quadratic, and cubic trends.
In the second analysis, you will end up with a large number of comparisons (30*29/2 = 435 of them) and I think it will be a stretch for most readers to understand that you are comparing trends at different points and/or different degrees. Be careful what you wish for. I strongly suggest re-thinking what is really important to communicate here. Since you are fitting a smooth surface, I'd hope you try to display it graphically. And if you want to do comparisons, wouldn't it make more sense to compare fitted values (aka emmeans) rather than trends?

Thank you for your reply, I've updated my question. In fact, my primary objective was to compare the fitted values but I thought that this was only possible when the variable was a factor before your answer. So I guess the first analysis is no longer relevant. By the way, I also include a graphical display of the model.
